# Finding the smallest chord that passes through a point

Tags: geometry, circles

I'm having some trouble with the following exercise:

> Let $A$ be a point inside a circumference. Determine the smallest chord that passes through $A$.

So my guess was that the smallest chord that passes through $A$ is the one that is perpendicular to the segment $AA'$ in the following picture ($[MN]$):

[image]

I think that this is the correct answer but I'm having some trouble proving this.

Is this correct? If so, how can I prove this?

Comment: I don't have time right now but this is an optimization problem: what you must do is find the minimum of the function describing the length of the chord restricted by the circle.

Comment: Hint: The product $AM\cdot AN$ is constant.

Comment: I thought the same, but this is a Geometry class, I'm not allowed to use things like functions, derivatives and things like that to do the optimization. @Simone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

For any chord $PQ$ which is not perpendicular to $OA$, $OA \geq OS$ where $OS$ is perp to $PQ$. In other words, $OA$ is the maximum perpendicular distance from center to any chord passing through $A$.

If $r$ is radius of the circle, $l$ is chord length and $d$ is perpendicular distance from center to the chord,

$l^2 = 4 (r^2-d^2)$

$l$ is minimum when $d$ is maximum, which is $OA$.

Comment: How did you arrive at the conclusion that $l^2 = 4(r^2 - d^2)$?

Comment: If $l$ is chord length, half of it is $l/2$. Applying Pythagoras $r^2 = (l/2)^2 + d^2$ as $d$ is perpendicular distance from center to the chord and that divides chord into half.

Comment: Take $\triangle OQS$ for example where $OS$ is the perpendicular distance from center to the chord, $OQ$ is the radius and $SQ$ is half of chord length.

Answer (score 2):

Draw any chord through $A$. Let its mid-point be $P$.

The length of the chord is equal to $2\sqrt{r^2 - OP^2}$.

We know that $AP \perp OP$. We have $OP^2 + AP^2 = OA^2$.

Hence the length of the chord is equal to $2\sqrt{r^2 - OA^2 +AP^2}$.

Since both $r$ and $OA$ are fixed, to minimize the length is to minimize $AP$.

When $AP = 0$, $A$ is the mid-point of the chord, and $OA$ is perpendicular to the chord.

Comment: Why is the length of the chord equal to $2(r^2 - OM^2)$?

Comment: It certainly helps to draw a diagram but I cannot do so right now. It comes down to the Pythagorean Theorem. Recall that the line drawn from the center to the mid-point of a chord is perpendicular to the chord.

Comment: If you do not use you own figure you should not introduce new points with names which are already used.

Comment: Missed the fact that $M$ was in use, changed to $P$. $M,N$ are standard 'notations' for mid-points.

Answer (score 2):

We show that

> a chord bisected at a given point in a circle, is the shortest chord through that point.

Let the chord bisected have length $x,x$ on either side of the given point. Draw any other chord through that point which has segments $a,b$, as divided by the point and $a \neq b$.

We know by [intersecting chords theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersecting_chords_theorem),
$$x\cdot x = a\cdot b$$
$$\Rightarrow x=\sqrt{x^2}=\sqrt{ab}\lt \frac{a+b}{2}$$
$$\Rightarrow 2x \lt a+b$$

using AM-GM inequality. That is, $2x$ is shorter than length of any other chord through the point.

Comment: Good to see a different answer. This was my first thought and then saw a comment from $OP$ that they wanted a geometric solution.